# Ошибка "RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type Morse was never called" PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Возникает ошибка:

> RuntimeError: super-class **init**() of type Morse was never called,

хотя класс `__init__` используется.

Также написано, что ошибка на 59 строке. Программа работает, если убрать все классы, кроме `MyWidget`, но их нужно оставить. Для запуска требуется дизайн программы, который расположен в отдельном файле, его тоже прилагаю.
Основной код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from Design import Ui_form

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        if self.encrypt.isChecked():
            if self.comboBox.activated[str]:
                Morse().convert(self.input.toPlainText())


class Morse(MyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rus_to_morse = {'а': '.-',
                             'б': '-...',
                             'в': '.--',
                             'г': '--.',
                             'д': '-..',
                             'е': '.',
                             'ж': '...-',
                             'з': '--..',
                             'и': '..',
                             'й': '.---',
                             'к': '-.-',
                             'л': '.-..',
                             'м': '--',
                             'н': '-.',
                             'о': '---',
                             'п': '.--.',
                             'р': '.-.',
                             'с': '...',
                             'т': '-',
                             'у': '..-',
                             'ф': '..-.',
                             'х': '....',
                             'ц': '-.-.',
                             'ч': '---.',
                             'ш': '----',
                             'щ': '--.-',
                             'ъ': '.--.-.',
                             'ы': '-.--',
                             'ь': '-..-',
                             'э': '..-..',
                             'ю': '..--',
                             'я': '.-.-'}
        self.o = []

    def convert(self, wordd):
        for i in wordd.split():
            self.o.append(" ".join(self.rus_to_morse[simv] for simv in i.lower()))
        print(wordd.split())
        print(wordd)
        print(self.o)
        print("  ".join(self.o))
        self.output.setText("  ".join(self.o))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Дизайн:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'DESIGN.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_form(object):
    def setupUi(self, form):
        form.setObjectName("form")
        form.resize(735, 847)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 90, 281, 41))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 231, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 300, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 140, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.encrypt = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(form)
        self.encrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 170, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.encrypt.setFont(font)
        self.encrypt.setObjectName("encrypt")
        self.decrypt = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(form)
        self.decrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 170, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.decrypt.setFont(font)
        self.decrypt.setObjectName("decrypt")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 210, 561, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.key_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(form)
        self.key_line.setEnabled(True)
        self.key_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 250, 431, 41))
        self.key_line.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.key_line.setFrame(True)
        self.key_line.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.key_line.setReadOnly(False)
        self.key_line.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.key_line.setObjectName("key_line")
        self.output = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(form)
        self.output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 640, 651, 192))
        self.output.setObjectName("output")
        self.run_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(form)
        self.run_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 540, 181, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.run_button.setFont(font)
        self.run_button.setObjectName("run_button")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(form)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 590, 751, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 600, 221, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.input = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(form)
        self.input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 340, 651, 191))
        self.input.setObjectName("input")

        self.retranslateUi(form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(form)

    def retranslateUi(self, form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        form.setWindowTitle(_translate("form", "Программа для шифрования"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("form", "Азбука Морзе"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("form", "Азбука Морзе"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("form", "Шифр Цезаря"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("form", "Шифр Вижнера"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("form", "Шифр Гронсфельда"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("form", "Выберете шифр:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("form", "Введите текст:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("form", "Вы хотите..."))
        self.encrypt.setText(_translate("form", "Зашифровать текст"))
        self.decrypt.setText(_translate("form", "Расшифровать текст"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("form", "Введите ключ(буквенный для ш. Вижнера, циферный для ш. Гронсфельда): "))
        self.run_button.setText(_translate("form", "Преобразовать текст"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("form", "Преобразованный текст:"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_form()
    ui.setupUi(form)
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

потому что после наследования от класса и перекрытия метода `__init__()` следует вызывать родительский `__init__`. в данном случае

```
class Morse(MyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rus_to_morse = {'а': '.-',
                             'б': '-...',
                             'в': '.--',
                             'г': '--.',
                             'д':
        ...
        super().__init__()
```

Забавный факт, в классе MyWidget родительский init вы все таки вызвали

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но теперь зашифрованный текст выводится только в консоль, а должен еще и на экран интерфейса программы

Comment: ну вот это уже другой вопрос. init у виджета принимает аргумент parent который должен указывать на родителя этого виджета. поробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения. Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from Design import Ui_form
class Ui_form(object):
    def setupUi(self, form):
        form.setObjectName("form")
        form.resize(735, 847)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 90, 281, 41))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 231, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 300, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 140, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.encrypt = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(form)
        self.encrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 170, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.encrypt.setFont(font)
        self.encrypt.setObjectName("encrypt")
        self.decrypt = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(form)
        self.decrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 170, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.decrypt.setFont(font)
        self.decrypt.setObjectName("decrypt")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 210, 561, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.key_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(form)
        self.key_line.setEnabled(True)
        self.key_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 250, 431, 41))
        self.key_line.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.key_line.setFrame(True)
        self.key_line.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.key_line.setReadOnly(False)
        self.key_line.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.key_line.setObjectName("key_line")
        
        self.output = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(form)
        self.output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 640, 651, 192))
        self.output.setObjectName("output")
        font = QtGui.QFont()                                                   # +
        font.setPointSize(22)                                                  # +                                              
        self.output.setFont(font)                                              # +
        
        self.run_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(form)
        self.run_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 540, 181, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.run_button.setFont(font)
        self.run_button.setObjectName("run_button")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(form)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 590, 751, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(form)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 600, 221, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.input = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(form)
        self.input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 340, 651, 191))
        self.input.setObjectName("input")

        self.retranslateUi(form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(form)

    def retranslateUi(self, form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        form.setWindowTitle(_translate("form", "Программа для шифрования"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("form", "Азбука Морзе"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("form", "Азбука Морзе"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("form", "Шифр Цезаря"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("form", "Шифр Вижнера"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("form", "Шифр Гронсфельда"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("form", "Выберете шифр:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("form", "Введите текст:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("form", "Вы хотите..."))
        self.encrypt.setText(_translate("form", "Зашифровать текст"))
        self.decrypt.setText(_translate("form", "Расшифровать текст"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("form", "Введите ключ(буквенный для ш. Вижнера, циферный для ш. Гронсфельда): "))
        self.run_button.setText(_translate("form", "Преобразовать текст"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("form", "Преобразованный текст:"))
        
        

class Morse(QtCore.QObject):                                           # - MyWidget
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                   # parent
        super(Morse, self).__init__(parent)                            # parent
        
        self.parent = parent                                           # parent
    
        self.rus_to_morse = {
            'а': '.-', 'б': '-...', 'в': '.--', 'г': '--.', 'д': '-..',
            'е': '.', 'ж': '...-', 'з': '--..', 'и': '..', 'й': '.---',
            'к': '-.-', 'л': '.-..', 'м': '--', 'н': '-.', 'о': '---',
            'п': '.--.', 'р': '.-.', 'с': '...', 'т': '-', 'у': '..-',
            'ф': '..-.', 'х': '....', 'ц': '-.-.', 'ч': '---.', 'ш': '----',
            'щ': '--.-', 'ъ': '.--.-.', 'ы': '-.--', 'ь': '-..-',
            'э': '..-..', 'ю': '..--', 'я': '.-.-'}
        self.o = []

    def convert(self, wordd):
        for i in wordd.split():
            self.o.append(" ".join(self.rus_to_morse[simv] for simv in i.lower()))
        print(wordd.split())
        print(wordd)
        print(self.o)
        print("  ".join(self.o))
#        self.output.setText("  ".join(self.o))
        self.parent.output.setText("  ".join(self.o))                    # parent


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.morse  = Morse(self)                                         # !!! 

        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        if self.encrypt.isChecked():
            if self.comboBox.activated[str]:
#                Morse().convert(self.input.toPlainText())
                self.morse.convert(self.input.toPlainText())              # !!!
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Nikita2431 я ответил на ваш вопрос ???